# Package dependéncies cannot be resolved

Tags: updates, dependencies

I use Ubuntu 20.04 and today the system got updated.

[image: Screenshot]

But I can install it. An error - `Package dependencies cannot be resolved`

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `aptitude`:

`sudo aptitude install <package-name>`

If you don't have `aptitude` installed on your machine `sudo apt-get install aptitude`.

Comment: Thanks friend, it really helped!

Answer (score 0):

Please try: `sudo apt --fix-broken install`

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libfprint-2-tod1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.